# Unable to pull image via GitLab Dependency Proxy

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, nexus, docker-registry, docker-proxy

I’m unable to pull image via Dependency Proxy.  I login to proxy with : `docker login my.gitlab.com`   then with below command pull docker image
`my.gitlab.com:443/groups/mygroup/dependency_proxy/containers/busybox:latest`

but get this error: `Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""`

GitLab service run with docker and the ports 80,443 are published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using my.gitlab.com:443/mygroup/dependency_proxy/containers/busybox:latest

This solved problem for me.